# Complex SQL Join on sub query with top 1 records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to write a query that looks something like below.

```
select t1.t1c1, t1.t1c2, t2.t2c3, t2.t2c4
from table1 t1 
left outer join (select top 1 t2c1, t2c2, t2c3, t2c4 from table2 
                 where t2c5 in (select t3c1 from table3 t3
                                where **t3c2 = t1.t1c2 and t3c3 = t1.t1c3**) t2
           on t1.t1c1 = t2.t2c1 and t1.t1c2 = t2.t2c2
```

What SQL Server does not allow is the highlighted text above - i.e. referencing the table1's columns in the table3 sub query.
Is there a way to achieve this?
I understand that this might not be the most optimal way, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to exactly want `outer apply`.  I think it would look like this:

```
select t1.t1c1, t1.t1c2, t2.t2c3, t2.t2c4
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top 1 t2c1, t2c2, t2c3, t2c4
      from table2 
      where t2c5 in (select t3c1
                     from table3 t3
                     where t3c2 = t1.t1c2 and t3c3 = t1.t1c3
                    ) and
            t1.t1c1 = t2.t2c1 and t1.t1c2 = t2.t2c2
     ) t2;
```

`APPLY` is a lot like using a correlated subquery, except it goes in the `FROM` clause and can return multiple columns and multiple rows.

Note:  You should be using `ORDER BY` when you use `TOP`.

Comment: Also `APPLY` can return more than one

Comment: Is there any equivalent in `Oracle`,`Postgres` or in any DBMS for `APPLY` operator. I really like its flexible functionality

Comment: Thanks @Gordon! You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: @Chris . . . They are called lateral joins and are in the most recent versions of Postgres and Oracles.